# SQL - How to select a value based on the max of another?

Tags: mysql, sql

If it have a table as below:
[image: DB Table]

I want to get each shops top salesperson, their total sales and the stores manager.
If i query and get the max total sales and group by shop title, how do I also get the correct salesperson?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use inner join on subquery for max sales

```
select m.salesperson, t.max_sales, t.shop_title
from my_table m 
inner join (
    select max(sales) max_sales, shop_title
    from my_table
    group by shop_title
) t on t.shop_title = m.shop_title and t.max_sale = m.sales
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.total_sales = (select max(t2.total_sales)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.shop_title = t.shop_title
                      );
```

Comment: But this query doesn't show you the "other" top sales person name.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I don't know what you mean.  This returns the top sales record for each shop, which seems to be what the OP wants.